# proper way retrieve a specific list of data from SQLite to a listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can someone help me how to retrieve specific list data from sql to listview i've tried to retrieve all data and it works succesfully but when i try to retrieve specific data using a Where clause it crashes. Any help? or is there other way to retrive specific list of data

This is the part of the code i try to retrieve the sql data

```
ArrayList<String> results=new ArrayList<>();
    db=new DBHandler(this);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    lst.setText(callquiz);
    String YOUR_QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE title= "+ callquiz;
//callquiz is a string variable i use to hold the data specifier for my table
    SQLiteDatabase dbfectch;
    dbfectch = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = dbfectch.rawQuery(YOUR_QUERY,null);
    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {  results.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_ANS)));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the DBHandler class

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DB_NAME = "AnswerTables.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
public static final String TABLE = "user";
public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
public static final String ID = "id";
public static final String COL_ANS="answer";
public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createtable="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ( "+ ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+ COL_TASK_TITLE+ " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ COL_ANS+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
    db.execSQL(createtable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String name,String quiz){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contex=new ContentValues();
    contex.put(COL_TASK_TITLE,name);
    contex.put(COL_ANS,quiz);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE,null,contex);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: can u add the crash log here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons (I'm not really sure) whenever you make a Where or another type of statement which matches values or so, the matched values should go like "?", so your statement would look like this

```
String QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE title=?";
```

And the remain code would look like this:

```
//callquiz is a string variable i use to hold the data specifier for my table
SQLiteDatabase dbfectch;
dbfectch = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = dbfectch.rawQuery(QUERY, new String[]{callquiz});
```

In case the query doesn't return any data, try to put the apostrophes between the "?" at the statement.

Answer (score 0):

#### The main issue

Your issue is likely due to a column name not being found.

This is because you are not enclosing the callquiz string in quotes and if the value is not a number then it takes the value as being a column name.

This issue could be fixed by using :-

```
String YOUR_QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE title= '"+ callquiz + "'";
```

#### Improvement by using the query convenience method.

However, the better way which would protect against such an error would be to instead utilise the SQLiteDatabase class's **query** convenience method. This also protects against SQL injection.

To utilise this you code could instead of being :-

String YOUR_QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE title= "+ callquiz;
//callquiz is a string variable i use to hold the data specifier for my table
    SQLiteDatabase dbfectch;
    dbfectch = db.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = dbfectch.rawQuery(YOUR_QUERY,null);

be :-

```
//String YOUR_QUERY  = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE title= "+ callquiz; //<<<<<<<<<< NOT NEEDED
//callquiz is a string variable i use to hold the data specifier for my table
SQLiteDatabase dbfectch;
dbfectch = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = dbfectch.query(DBHandler.TABLE, //<<<<<<<<<< The table to query
               null,                       //<<<<<<<<<< The columns null for all eqv to *
               DBHandler.COL_TASK_TITLE + "=?", //<<<<<<<<<< The WHERE clause ? is replaced on a 1 for 1 basis from the WHERE args (next paramter)
               new String[]{callquiz}, //<<<<<<<<<< The WHERE args that replace ?
               null, //<<<<<<<<<< GROUP BY clause, null = no clause
               null, //<<<<<<<<<< HAVING clause, null = no clause
               null //<<<<<<<<<< ORDER BY clause, null = no clause
            );
```

- Note the respective keywords are provided and should not be included
- The above would result in the query being as per the fix including enclosing the string in single quotes.

#### Checking a Cursor for null

On the subject of correctness checking a Cursor returned from an SQLiteDabase method for **null** is useless and can result in issues. Such a Cursor will never be null, rather if now rows are extracted the Cursor will have 0 rows. The moveTo?????? methods will instead return false if the move cannot be made (additionally the Cursor **getCount** method would return 0).

#### Simpler loop using `while (cursor.moveToNext) {....}`

It is simpler to use `while (cursor.MoveToNext) { do your stuff.... }` to iterate through the Cursor. As such the more correct code could be :-

```
SQLiteDatabase dbfectch;
dbfectch = db.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = dbfectch.query(DBHandler.TABLE, //<<<<<<<<<< The table to query
               null,                       //<<<<<<<<<< The columns null for all eqv to *
               DBHandler.COL_TASK_TITLE + "=?", //<<<<<<<<<< The WHERE clause ? is replaced on a 1 for 1 basis from the WHERE args (next parameter)
               new String[]{callquiz}, //<<<<<<<<<< The WHERE args that replace ?
               null, //<<<<<<<<<< GROUP BY clause, null = no clause
               null, //<<<<<<<<<< HAVING clause, null = no clause
               null //<<<<<<<<<< ORDER BY clause, null = no clause
            );
while (c.moveToNext()) {
   results.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHandelr.COL_ANS)));
}
```

#### Utilise a single adapter

At some time the list may change (e.g. you might have code that deletes a row), you don't really want to instantiate a new adapter each time rather you would refresh the list via a call to the adapter's NotifyDatasetChanged method. As such it's not really good coding to then follow with just :-

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Rather you could use :-

```
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
    adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

- Note this doesn't cater for rebuilding the results ArrayList it also assumes that adapter has been declared as a class variable (as results could be to better facilitate redbuilding it prior to invoking the notifyDatasetChanged method).

#### Limitations of ArrayList

Often you will want the user to interact with the list (e.g. to long click an item for it to be deleted (just clicking is inadvisable without an intermediate dialog to confirm deletion, a long click at least offers some protection against inadvertent clicks)).

The issue with using **ArrayList** is that only the displayed String is directly available and that may be insufficient to identify the underlying row. Rather ArrayList would be better, as you'd typically have such an object (in your case perhaps the *your_more_comprehensive_object* could be a **user** object that includes the value of the respective **ID** column). However, without utilising a CustomAdapter or overiding the toString method in the object's class you'd be restricted.

For a ListView the simpler solution is to instead utilise a Cursor Adapter. Utilising a CursorAdapter (e.g. SimpleCursorAdapter) does require that a column specifically named **_id** exists.

#### Working Example using SimpleCursorAdapter with Listeners

As such you may wish to consider the following working example which is based upon your code (hopefully the comments along with the explanation above will explain everything) :-

**DBHanlder.java**

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "AnswerTables.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    public static final String TABLE = "user";
    public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
    //public static final String ID = "id"; //<<<<<<<<<< replaced by line below
    public static final String ID = BaseColumns._ID; //<<<<<<<<<< make column the standard _id
    public static final String COL_ANS="answer";
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createtable="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ( "+ ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ COL_TASK_TITLE+ " TEXT NOT NULL,"+ COL_ANS+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(createtable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData(String name,String quiz){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contex=new ContentValues();
        contex.put(COL_TASK_TITLE,name);
        contex.put(COL_ANS,quiz);
        long result=db.insert(TABLE,null,contex);
        if(result==-1)
        {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< new method
    public Cursor getAllUsersWithTitle(String title) {
        String whereclause = COL_TASK_TITLE + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{title};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< new method
    public boolean deleteUserById(long id) {
        String whereclause = ID + "=?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return (db.delete(TABLE,whereclause,whereargs) > 0);
    }
}
```

- Note to incorporate the above you'd need to do one of the following :-

  - delete/clear the App's data
  - uninstall the App
  - increase the value assigned to DB_version as the DB structure/schema is changed
- Note you very likely don't need/want AUTOINCREMENT and it's overheads see [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for Toast from handler
    ListView listView;
    DBHandler db;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    String callquiz;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        listView = this.findViewById(R.id.list);

        db = new DBHandler(this);
        addSomeUsers(); //<<<<<<<<<< Add some testing data
        callquiz = "Fred";
        refreshOrInitialiseListView(); //<<<<<<<<<< handle the listview

        //<<<<<<<<<< EXTRA >>>>>>>>>>
        //<<<<<<<<<< Add A click Listener to toast the clicked item
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "You clicked on the Item with a title of " +
                                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.COL_TASK_TITLE)) +
                                " and ans is " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.COL_ANS)) +
                                " whose ID is " + String.valueOf(l) //<<<<<<<<<< note 4th parameter passed is the id
                        ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                db.deleteUserById(l);
                refreshOrInitialiseListView();
                return true; //<<<<<<<<<<<< indicate that the long click has been handled
            }
        });
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to clean up (not needed for the main activity but does not hurt)
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to refresh the ListView is the activity is resumed e.g. return from invoked activity.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshOrInitialiseListView();
    }

    private void refreshOrInitialiseListView() {
        cursor = db.getAllUsersWithTitle(callquiz);
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    cursor,
                    new String[]{DBHandler.COL_TASK_TITLE,DBHandler.COL_ANS},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            listView.setAdapter(sca);
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }

    private void addSomeUsers() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db.getWritableDatabase(),DBHandler.TABLE) < 1) {
            db.insertData("Fred","Freds Quiz");
            db.insertData("Fred","Fred's 2nd Quiz");
            db.insertData("Fred","Fred's 3rd quiz");
            db.insertData("Mary","Mary's first quiz");
            db.insertData("Mary","mary's 2nd quiz");
            db.insertData("Mary","Mary's 3rd quiz");
        }
    }
}
```

Running the App from scratch will result in 3 of the 6 rows (items) being listed in the ListView (with title and answer displayed).

- Clicking an item will result in the Item's details being toasted.
- Long Clicking an item will delete that item from the table and additionally from the list.

**Note** The working example is designed to be a demonstration and has limitations (e.g. if you delete all the items/rows then unless you delete the database nothing will then be displayed)